# iAD Network Module Missing

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect, iad

I have agreed on the terms of iAD Network and all my contracts are in the effect.
I have three different apps with iAD enabled, that are 'Ready for Sale' on the app store for at least 10 days but still I can't see the iAD Network module in my iTunes Connect main view... 
I wonder if anybody have or had similar issue, and how should I deal with that problem?
Apple Support is silent, and doesn't answer for my emails...
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was problem on Apple's side. 
They solved the problem after contacting them